# UICollectionView cell changes color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

trying to set the cell.cellLabel.text with a specific color when the cell.cellLabel.text is a specific value. However the cell.text color is also set for random cells and changes when scrolling. ?? Any thoughts ?

Simply..

```
cell.cellLabel.text = [cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([cell.cellLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Phonograms"] ) {
    cell.cellLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 }
```

Thanks 
John.

Comment: Are you providing static data from storyBoard in cells ? if yes remove text from there as you are providing data through code too. Just Try if it works

Answer (score 0):

Add an else block i think it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
cell.cellLabel.text = [cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([cell.cellLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Phonograms"] ) {
    cell.cellLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
else {
    // Set default color for other cell like below
    cell.cellLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Comment: Been out, But thanks it worked perfectly. Should of thought of that ..